# Play video when mouse hovers trigger object

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm designing a page where i want the video for each post to play when the user hovers the post. I've set it up like this:

```
<div class="project-link-block">
<div class="video-cover">
<video class="playonhover"height="100%" width="100%" muted playsinline loop data-object-fit="cover">
   
<source src="https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/671122426/rendition/720p?loc=external&signature=e1562e4b2a73a9f37492359547fef09f8a3ed47a9d12fd77089930fc656a7d8e" type="video/mp4">
Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>

</div>
</div>
```

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".playonhover").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    this.play();

  }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.pause();

  });
})
</script>
```

This works, but I actually want the video to play when the top div (class .project-link-block) is hovered, not the video itself. Is there any way to do this? Switching the class in the JS didn't work. Using Webflow for this, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also change `this` when you switched the class? Once you switch the class, the video element is no longer `this`.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="project-link-block">
  <div class="video-cover">
    <video class="playonhover" height="100%" width="100%" muted playsinline loop data-object-fit="cover">
      <source
        src="https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/671122426/rendition/720p?loc=external&signature=e1562e4b2a73a9f37492359547fef09f8a3ed47a9d12fd77089930fc656a7d8e"
        type="video/mp4">
      Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".video-cover").on("mouseover", function (event) {
      $(".playonhover").get(0).play();
    }).on('mouseout', function (event) {
      $(".playonhover").get(0).pause();
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't! I'm pretty new at JS. What should it be changes to? The class name?

Comment: Not the class name, but the DOM element which corresponds to that class (`playonhover`). To get the element, you should select it, just like you've already done, using `$(".playonhover")`.

Comment: Okey, so that the whole code is like this?

`<script> 

$(document).ready(function() {
 
$(".project-link-block").on("mouseover", function(event) {
    this.play();

 
 }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.pause();

  });
})
</script>
`
That doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the code. Note that since `play` & `pause` aren't JQuery, you need to go through `get(0)`. Anyhow, it should work. Let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: Hi! This kind of works, but the problem is that there are several videos on the page. When I implement this it only play one of the videos. Is it possible to connect this to the parent div, somehow?

Comment: @marteteigen Add `class="playonhover"` to the opening tags of all the videos you want to be affected, then replace `$(".playonhover").get(0).play();` with `const videos = document.getElementsByClassName("playonhover"); for (const video of videos) { video.play(); };`, and do the same for `pause()`. Explanation: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all those videos, and then you loop them and call `play()` on each.

Answer (score 0):

See if this code below achieves your expected result. Then convert to JQuery (if required).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="project-link-block">
<div class="video-cover">
<video class="playonhover"height="100%" width="100%" muted playsinline loop data-object-fit="cover">

<!-- <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> -->
<source type="video/mp4"
src="https://player.vimeo.com/progressive_redirect/playback/671122426/rendition/720p?loc=external&signature=e1562e4b2a73a9f37492359547fef09f8a3ed47a9d12fd77089930fc656a7d8e" 
>

Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>

</div>
</div>

<script> 

window.addEventListener( "load", on_documentReady );

function on_documentReady() 
{
    //const myTargets = document.getElementsByClassName("playonhover");
    const myTargets = document.getElementsByClassName("project-link-block");

    for (var i = 0; i < myTargets.length; i++) 
    { 
        myTargets[i].onmouseover = handle_mouseOver;
        myTargets[i].onmouseout = handle_mouseOut;
    }
}

function handle_mouseOver( evt ) 
{
    //alert( "## was rolled over" );
    evt.target.play();
}

function handle_mouseOut( evt ) 
{
    //alert( "## was rolled out" );
    evt.target.pause();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```